# Show footer at the bottom of the page always problem with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer-11, footer

I'm developing an `ASP.NET` website with `Visual Studio 2019`, `C#` and `.NET Framework 4.7`

On the masterpage I have inserted this `css class` because all my pages have vertical scrollbar and I want to show `<footer>` always at the bottom of the page.

On the browsers `Google Chrome` and `Microsoft Edge` this `css class` working correctly, but in browser `Internet Explorer 11` the footer text moves along with the web page.

How can I do it?

```
footer{
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
}

<div>
    <footer>
        <p style="font-size:20px">My Company</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: Please provide more details, what is happening on the page, can you inspect the element and see if the classes are being applied fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actualy working fine all browser, just make sure that you set CSS correctly.

- CSS in `style` in `head`
- CSS inline

### DEMO:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
      .p{
        height: 200vh;
        background:red;
      }
      footer{
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        background: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p class="p">This is a paragraph.</p>
    <div>
        <footer>
            <p style="font-size:20px">My Company</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

### Result on IE11 (you can I scrolled because half of title):

[image]